# Rewrite apache2 location header response

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

My apache2 server is running behind a proxy server. Apache2 doesn't know about which hostnames are used publicly for the sites it's hosting.

So this request:

```
https://www.example.com/zever
```

Is sent to apache like this:

```
http://somedomain.localhost/zever
```

This all works fine... until apache needs to do some kind of redirect.

It ignores the `X-Forwarded-Host` header set by the proxy, and sends this response header to the client:

```
location: http://somedomain.localhost/zever/
```

I've looked at several ways to make apache use the `X-Forwarded-Host` value instead of the current server alias or server name, with things like `UseCanonicalName` and such, but those did not work.

I did stumble upon this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297233/how-to-rewrite-location-response-header-in-a-proxy-setup-with-apache, which lets you edit the location header by making it relative, which would solve most of my issues.

So I tried adding this to my configuration:

```
Header edit Location "(^http[s]?://)([^/]+)" ""
```

The only problem is: it doesn't work. Absolutely nothing is changed to the `location` response header. Other calls (like `Header always set Zever bla`) work fine.

I'm running Apache/2.4.18 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You should not need to adjust for that in your back-end server.  The reverse proxy IS aware of both the domain name and URL path  used in the incoming request and the mapping to the hostname/path your backend servers uses and (when configured correctly) should rewrite and  301 / 302 redirect responses and `Location` headers for you. That is what for instance in Apache [`ProxyPassReverse`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse)  directive does and as far as I know all other reverse proxies should have similar settings. Fix the reverse proxy, not apache.